# Find the $n$^th term sum of $1+(2+3*4)+(5+6*7+8*9*10 )+ \cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series

So, recently, in a programming problem, I solved it with some coding, but I tried to find any mathematical relation to the series, but I couldn't. Please let me know if any of it. I am sharing my C++ programming code of it.

Find the sum of nth term of $1+(2+3*4)+(5+6*7+8*9*10)+\cdots$.
So, here the first term is 1, second term is $2+3*4 $and third term is $5+6*7+8*9*10$

And my code of it was:
[image: Code of the series sum]

Comment: Multiplying $n$ numbers together is going to be way too big for C++ ints to handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the sum $S_n.$ Then $S_{n+1} = S_n + a_n$ where $a_n$ is the $n$-th term. Now if you look at $a_n$, then it appears to be a sum of $n$ different terms itself. But if you just figure out the first number that's summed in $a_n$, then the remaining summands are easily found.

So look at the first numbers in each brackets - $1,2,5,11,....$ This is a simple recurrence relation to solve:
$$x_1 = 1,x_2 = 2,\, x_{n+1} = x_n + \dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}.$$

So $$x_n = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k(k-1)}{2} = 1 + \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{12}  - \dfrac{n(n+1)}{4}.$$

Now this is the first number in $n$-th parenthesis and so you can technically write down and compute that $n$-th term. However, its last term is a product of $n$ consecutive numbers starting from $x_{n+1} - n$ and this will result in a polynomial of degree $3n$ in $n$. So I do not think a simple closed form for this $n$-th term exists, let alone for the whole sum.

Answer (score 1):

As the previous comment says, I do not think that a simple close form expression exists. However, for a large $n$, the $n$-th term, denoted by $T_n$, satisfies

\begin{equation}
      T_n  \sim \left[\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{6}+1\right]^n
\end{equation}

This follows since

\begin{equation}
       T_n= \prod_{i=1}^n (x_{n+1}-i)+\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} (x_{n+1}-n-i)+\cdots+x_{n}
\end{equation}

Therefore,

\begin{equation}
     (x_{n+1}-n)^n \leq T_n\leq (x_{n+1})^n + (x_{n+1})^{n-1}+ x_{n+1}\leq \frac{(x_{n+1})^{n+1}}{x_{n+1}-1}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
     \left(1-\frac{n}{x_{n+1}}\right)^n \leq \frac{T_n}{(x_{n+1})^n}\leq \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_{n+1}-1}
\end{equation}

Next, using that $x_n=\frac{(n-1)n (n+1)}{6}+1$,

\begin{equation}
      \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left(1-\frac{n}{x_{n+1}}\right)^n= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_{n+1}-1} =1
\end{equation}

this is $T_n \sim (x_{n+1})^n$.